# How to get correct value for CurrentCulture?

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8

On an iPhone, the user can choose his display language and the region that is used for formatting.
The display language is equivalent to .NET's `Thread.CurrentUICulture`, i.e. the language of the UI.
The formatting region is equivalent to .NET's `Thread.CurrentCulture`, i.e the culture settings to be used for formatting numbers, dates etc.

Assume the following settings:
Language: English
Region: Germany

In iOS6, NSLocale.CurrentLocale would return `"de_DE"`, which I could easily transform into a `CultureInfo` object.
However, since then, things have changed.
For example, on iOS8, I get `"en_DE"` which is an invalid value for a `CultureInfo`.

So, what is the preferred way to make sure that my Xamarin.iOS application takes into account the settings chosen by the user, i.e. how do I get the correct value for `Thread.CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I just answered my own question:

Changing the Region to Germany doesn't actually change the formatting as long as the user didn't explicitly switch off "Automatic" in the Regions advanced settings and changed that language to German, too. Only in that case, is the formatting actually different from the UI language.

Based on that, I am using this code now:

```
private static CultureInfo GetFormattingLanguage()
{
    try
    {
        return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(
            NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier.Replace('_', '-'));
    }
    catch (CultureNotFoundException)
    {
        return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LanguageCode);
    }
}
```